# UIDocumentInteractionController & ARC: [UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This issue or similar issues have been discussed here before, but I didn't find any working solution for me.

I am using the following code to display a `UIDocumentInteractionController` on an ARC-enabled iOS 7 project:

```
- (void) exportDoc{
    // [...]
    docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    docController.delegate = self;
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:mainMenuButton animated:YES];
}
```

First I didn't want to create a property that holds the controller reference, but as many people said that there are not alternatives to it. It is defined as

```
@property (strong) UIDocumentInteractionController* docController;
```

`exportDoc` is run in the main thread using `NSOperationQueue`. Whenever it is executed, I get the following error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still
>   visible.'

This is what the backtrace says:

> ```
> (lldb) bt
> * thread #1: tid = 0x1c97d9, 0x000000019a23c1c0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread',
> stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
>     frame #0: 0x000000019a23c1c0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
>     frame #1: 0x000000018d982e90 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 128
>     frame #2: 0x0000000190bc348c UIKit`-[UIPopoverController dealloc] + 96
>     frame #3: 0x0000000190e18fc8 UIKit`-[UIDocumentInteractionController dealloc] + 168
>     frame #4: 0x000000019a255474 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 524
>     frame #5: 0x000000018d881988 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
>     frame #6: 0x000000018e42cb18 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 892
>     frame #7: 0x000000018e4eea38 Foundation`__NSOQSchedule_f + 76
>     frame #8: 0x000000019a813fd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
>     frame #9: 0x000000019a8171dc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 336
>     frame #10: 0x000000018d942c2c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
>     frame #11: 0x000000018d940f6c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1452
>     frame #12: 0x000000018d881c20 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
>     frame #13: 0x0000000193511c0c GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
>     frame #14: 0x00000001909b2fdc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1156   * frame #15: 0x000000010000947c MyApplication`main(argc=1,
> argv=0x000000016fdfbc80) + 108 at main.m:16
>     frame #16: 0x000000019a82faa0 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
> ```

As far as I understand the autoreleasepool just releases the controller. Shouldn't this be prevented by using a strong property just as I did?

Do you have any idea what the problem can be and how I can solve it?

[Edit]

I disabled ARC and manually added a `[docController retain]` and got it to work. I was wondering if ARC is really enabled on my project and tried the following preprocessor code

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
  #error no arc
#endif
```

but the error is not displayed.

Comment: You are assigning to `docController`. Have you specifically synthesized the property to this variable? Otherwise, you need to assign to `_docController`.

Comment: What class is this `exportDoc` method in? It would seem that it is being deallocated (and hence the `docController` ivar) while the `UIDocumentInteractionController` is still visible.

Comment: @LeoNatan yes, I called `@synthesize docController` in the implementation (.m) file.

Comment: @rmaddy The method is in my main view controller which is active and stays allocated all the time (there is no other).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like docController you are using is a local variable and not a class level variable. As you are using the local variable, it gets deallocated. Did you try using the property instead of iVar as below.

```
- (void) exportDoc{
    // [...]
   self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
   self.docController.delegate = self;
   [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:mainMenuButton animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: there are only checks before the code I posted, and no local variable called `doccontroller`. I nevertheless tried to replace it with `self.docController`, but it still does not work

Comment: Did you write an explicit @synthesis for the property docController? Or it's auto synthesized?

Comment: I wrote an explicit `@syntesize docController` in my ViewController implementation

Comment: Did you assign that to a iVar? Is it like this '@synthesis docController;' or  '@synthesis docController = docController;'   ?

Comment: it's just `@synthesize docController;`

Comment: I am just confused in that case your iVar has to be _docController and why your earlier code compiled? Is there any variable named docController ?

Comment: No, not in the whole project. And it works for me, even without self. Please consider [this example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9716a4278da965a02788) which compiles as well